# Combine json stat to return both id and label/value

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fetch

I want the regionValue to return as the key of the Region object, but it instead returns null?

My goal is to get:

```
{
    value: 1122000,
    Tid: '2020',
    ContentsCode: 'Samlet inntekt, median (kr)',
    HusholdType: 'Par med barn 0-17 år',
    Region: 'Ringerike',
regionValue:"3007"
  },
```

but this is what i've tried so far:

```
const JSONstat = require("jsonstat-toolkit");


var url="https://data.ssb.no/api/v0/dataset/49678.json?lang=no";


function test(){
    return JSONstat(url).then(main);
}
async function main(j){
    var ds=j.Dataset(0);
    let y="Region"
    let array = ds.toTable( { type : "arrobj" } ,function( d ){
        if ( d.value!==null){
            d.regionValue = ds.Dimension(y).Category(d.Region).id
           return d;
        }
     })
    console.log(array)
} 
test()
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Region dimension is only available as an object with `ID` -> `Label` so you can not directly search by Region name to obtain the ID.

As a workaround, you can create a new inverted object with `Label` => `ID` and use that to retrieve the RegionValue from the Region.

So in code

1. Declare a global variable which will contain your new object

```
assoc = {}
```

2. in your `main` method, loop all the Regions and populate your inverted object

Please note that the labels were displaying a date, so I used `split` to remove useless information that wouldn't allow a direct match on the Region name.

```
for(const key in ds.__tree__.dimension.Region.category.label) {
    let label = ds.__tree__.dimension.Region.category.label[key].split('(')[0].trim()
    assoc[label] = key
}
```

3. In your callback that runs for each element, read the ID from the `assoc` object you've just populated and assign its value to `d.regionValue`

```
if (d.value !== null) {
    d.regionValue = assoc[d.Region]
    return d;
}
```

When you output your array, it will show like this

```
0:
ContentsCode: "Samlet inntekt, median (kr)"
HusholdType: "Alle husholdninger"
Region: "Halden"
Tid: "2020"
regionValue: "0101"
value: 616000
```

Here's the full script

```
var url = "https://data.ssb.no/api/v0/dataset/49678.json?lang=no";
assoc = {}

function test() {
    return JSONstat(url).then(main);
}

async function main(j) {
    var ds = j.Dataset(0);
    for(const key in ds.__tree__.dimension.Region.category.label) {
        let label = ds.__tree__.dimension.Region.category.label[key].split('(')[0].trim()
                assoc[label] = key
    }
    let array = ds.toTable({
        type: "arrobj"
    }, function (d) {
        if (d.value !== null) {
            d.regionValue = assoc[d.Region]
            return d;
        }
    })
    console.log(array)
}

test()
```